# How do I colorize a texture with libGDX?

Tags: opengl, libgdx, textures

I'm working on a libGDX implementation for my library which draws ASCII tiles to create a text GUI. My current Swing + `BufferedImage` implementation looks like this:

[image]

This works by copying parts of a grayscale texture which has CP437 characters on it and transforming them by adding color to each pixel.

My problem is that my libGDX implementation does not work for some reason:

[image]

What I have tried is this:

```
    val backend: TextureRegion = region.getBackend()

    val texture = backend.texture
    if (!texture.textureData.isPrepared) {
        texture.textureData.prepare()
    }
    val pixmap = texture.textureData.consumePixmap()
    (0 until backend.regionWidth).forEach { x ->
        (0 until backend.regionHeight).forEach { y ->
            val color = Color(pixmap.getPixel(backend.regionX + x, backend.regionY + y))

            val ax = color.a
            var rx = color.r
            var gx = color.g
            var bx = color.b
            rx *= r
            gx *= g
            bx *= b
            if (ax < 50) {
                pixmap.drawPixel(backend.regionX + x, backend.regionY + y, textCharacter.getBackgroundColor().toAWTColor().rgb)
            } else {
                pixmap.drawPixel(backend.regionX + x, backend.regionY + yy, Color(rx, gx, bx, ax).toIntBits())
            }
        }
    }

    return region
```

I know that I am missing something but I just can't figure out what the problem is here. I've tried with various options like copying the `TextureRegion` but I can't get this to work.

My other implementation uses `BufferedImage`s and it just works:

```
    val r = textCharacter.getForegroundColor().getRed().toFloat() / 255
    val g = textCharacter.getForegroundColor().getGreen().toFloat() / 255
    val b = textCharacter.getForegroundColor().getBlue().toFloat() / 255

    val backend: BufferedImage = region.getBackend()
    (0 until backend.width).forEach { x ->
        (0 until backend.height).forEach { y ->
            val ax = backend.colorModel.getAlpha(backend.raster.getDataElements(x, y, null))
            var rx = backend.colorModel.getRed(backend.raster.getDataElements(x, y, null))
            var gx = backend.colorModel.getGreen(backend.raster.getDataElements(x, y, null))
            var bx = backend.colorModel.getBlue(backend.raster.getDataElements(x, y, null))
            rx = (rx * r).toInt()
            gx = (gx * g).toInt()
            bx = (bx * b).toInt()
            if (ax < 50) {
                backend.setRGB(x, y, textCharacter.getBackgroundColor().toAWTColor().rgb)
            } else {
                backend.setRGB(x, y, (ax shl 24) or (rx shl 16) or (gx shl 8) or (bx shl 0))
            }
        }
    }
    return region
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When the Texture is loaded, it copies the Pixmap data over to the GPU, so it is too late to start changing the Pixmap data. You are changing the source data, but not the image that's loaded to the GPU. The typical way to do this is to load the Pixmap directly first, modify it, and then pass it into a Texture constructor.

Also, make sure before editing the Pixmap that you set its blending to None instead of SourceOver. Otherwise calling `drawPixel` will alpha blend your pixel with what's already in the Pixmap.

A completely different method would be to modify it in real-time during rendering using a custom shader. For such a simple scene this would have a trivial performance impact. It would permit you to do real-time animations of the colors if you wanted to get fancy with your effects. I'm on a phone now so can't type out the instructions for doing that. Leave a comment if interested and I'll see if I can update the answer tomorrow.

Comment: What I have in my `BufferedImage`-based . codebase is that I put all the painted 16x16 textures (copied from the 256x256 `.png` file) into a cache so I don't have to redraw them over and over again. How is this handled with libGDX? Do I still need to cache? Do I cache the `Pixmap`s before creating `Texture`s out of them?

Comment: You don't have to cache. The Texture object has a native ID handle to the image loaded on the GPU. Just don't lose your Texture reference before calling dispose() on it so it can clear that native memory. Typically a game is redrawn continuously--the render() method is called over and over by the framework and you redraw the whole scene each time. But if your game is not continuously animated, this is wasteful. Look up "noncontinuous rendering" for LibGDX.